# Assigning a value to a textbox

Tags: sql, function, vba, ms-access

I am trying to assign the value of a table field to the textbox on my form and it keeps giving me errors...

```
Function getInjuryID(Socail As String)
  Dim dba As Database
  Dim rst As Recordset
  Dim SQL As String

  Set dba = CurrentDb

  SQL = "SELECT InjuryID,Employee_SSN FROM Injuries WHERE InjuryID IN(SELECT MAX(InjuryID) FROM Injuries GROUP BY Employee_SSN) AND Claim_StatusID = 'Open' AND Employee_SSN = " & Socail

  Set rst = dba.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

  Set Me.Recordset = rst

  Set dba = Nothing
  Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

Call...

```
Private Sub WcCaseYes_AfterUpdate()
  Me.InjuryID = getInjuryID(Me.SocialSecurityNumber.Value)

End Sub
```

It keeps giving me the error "You can't assign a value to this object??

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like we need a little more info... is Me.InjuryID a const or readonly field?

Comment: It's a textbox on my form

Comment: Are you trying to assign a string to the Textbox itself? Normally you set a property on the textbox like Me.InjuryID.Text. I haven't done VB in a long time but if it follows convention it should have a Text property.

Comment: Yes, I have tried value and text, neither are working so I'm a bit confounded.

Comment: I just set up a text box and combobox. The row source for the combobox is from a table. This code worked for me: `Me.CustomerId.Value = Me.Combo9.Value`... CustomerId is the name of a Textbox, Combo9 is the name of the combobox.

Comment: On another note, your Function has no `Return`. Also, your Function is returning 2 different fields. I think you're confused about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Newbie by not specifying a return type it is implied that it is `Variant`.

Answer (score 0):

The select query you wrote seems to be redundant. Try this one:

```
SELECT MAX(InjuryID) as maxInjuryID  FROM Injuries where Employee_SSN = SsnToLookUp and Claim_StatusID = 'Open'
```

You can set the value of a text box several ways

set the control source to an expression like

```
=DMax("InjuryID","Injuries", "Employee_SSN = " & <SsnToLookUp> & " and Claim_StatusID = 'Open'")
```

or you can open a recordset like you are trying to do and set the value of a a field to a control.

```
Function getInjuryID(Socail As String)
  Dim dba As DAO.Database
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim SQL As String

  Set dba = CurrentDb

  SQL = "SELECT MAX(InjuryID) as maxInjuryID FROM Injuries where Employee_SSN = " & Socail  & "and claim_StatusID = 'Open'"

  Set rst = dba.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

  if rst.recordcount>0 then
      getInjuryID = rst("maxInjuryID")
  end if
End Function
```

Although the safest way to do this is to use a paramaterized query (to prevent sql injection)

```
Function getInjuryID()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qdef As New DAO.QueryDef
    Dim sql As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb


    On Error Resume Next
    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("myq")
    If Err.Number = 3265 Then
        sql = "SELECT MAX(InjuryID) as maxInjuryID FROM Injuries where Employee_SSN = SocailToLookUp and claim_StatusID = 'Open'"
        db.CreateQueryDef "MyQ", sql
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("MyQ")
    qdef.Parameters("SocailToLookUp") = Social
    Set rst = qdef.OpenRecordset

    If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
        getInjuryID = rst("maxInjuryID")
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I'm glad you redirected the user in your answer. It's important to also note that the user was selecting an array `[InjuryID, Employee_SSN]` instead of the single `MAX(InjuryID)` it seems he/she was hoping to retrieve.

Comment: yeah, selecting two columns is not as much a big deal as you might thing though. Either way they can only return one value from the function and that column needs to be named.

Comment: I immediately thought that since he was selecting more than 1 field in his query it would have caused an error.